# How to ignore a validation rule if a field is null?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

I have these rules for 2 dates. But I want the before_or_equal rule to be followed only when retired_on date has been inputted. How do I do this? sometimes doesn't solve this problem. If there is no input on retired_on date, one has to be able to input entered_on without any errors. With these 2 rules, an error appears right at the beginning since retired_on default is blank.

```
'entered_on' => 'required|date_format:Y/m/d|before_or_equal:retired_on',
'retired_on' => 'date_format:Y/m/d|after_or_equal:entered_on',
```

Comment: I'm using Laravel 5.1. The nullable rule does not exist in this version. What am I to do? I can't upgrade as this is a job not a personal project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say you can't use `nullable` or upgrade the Laravel version, you could always separate it out and validate for that field conditionally.

```php
// your other input validations
$this->validate($request, [
    'entered_on' => 'required|date_format:Y/m/d|before_or_equal:retired_on',
]);

// only validate 'retired_on' if it exists and is not null
if ($request->has('retired_on') && !is_null($request->input('retired_on'))) {
    // pre-check passed, do validation
    $this->validate($request, [
        'retired_on' => 'date_format:Y/m/d|after_or_equal:entered_on',
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write the code! Much appreciation.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`nullable`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-nullable) rule:

```
'retired_on' => 'nullable|date_format:Y/m/d|after_or_equal:entered_on',
```

Comment: I added the nullable rule and what happens is that "Whoops, looks like something went wrong." is now always displayed.

Comment: @Lorenz are you sure retired_on in database is nullable already ? :)

Comment: I took a look at the migrations and yes retired_on is nullable together with entered_on.

Comment: BTW, I'm using Laravel 5.1 and the after_or_equal and before_or_equal I'm using is from a customized Validator.

Comment: I was looking at Laravel 5.1 tutorial and there is indeed no nullable rule. It appears I can't use the nullable rule. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Update your Laravel version.